# How to pass a @State var to another @State var as argument in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `@State var` as following:

```swift
@State private var quantity: Int = 1
```

And I use this variable in a `Button` as following:

```swift
Button { 
    cartViewModel.addProductToCart(product, quantity: quantity)
} label: {
    Text("Add to cart (\(quantity))")
        .bold()
        .padding(4)
}
```

I want to extract the title of the `Button` as a `String` and when an action happens I want to modify this `String` - so it's going to be a `@State` variable again.

But the problem is, I am not able to describe this `@State` property as `lazy` because I need to pass the `quantity` which is also a `@State` variable.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```swift
@State private lazy var buttonText: String = "Add to cart (\(quantity))"
```

Is there any way to handle this case in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

Use your own `init(...)` to create your state `buttonText` with initial string from your `quantity` value.
For example:

```
struct AnotherTestView: View {
    @State private var quantity: Int = 1
    @State private var buttonText: String = ""
    
    init() {
        _buttonText = State(initialValue: "Add to cart (\(self.quantity))")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(buttonText)
        Button("click me") {
            quantity += 1
            buttonText = "Add to cart (\(quantity))"
        }
    }
}
```

To update `buttonText` when `quantity` changes, use `didSet`:

```
struct AnotherTestView: View {
    @State private var quantity: Int {
        didSet {
            buttonText = "Add to cart (\(quantity))"
        }
    }
    
    @State private var buttonText: String = ""
    
    init() {
        self.quantity = 1
        _buttonText = State(initialValue: "Add to cart (\(self.quantity))")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(buttonText)
        Button("click me") {
            quantity += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it somehow possible to trigger an update on buttonText when quantity is updated?

Comment: updated my answer, using `didSet`

Comment: In this case you could define buttonText as a computed var using quantity state var.

Comment: Yes, sensible enough, you could use a computed var. There are other ways as well, but it may give you problems when you want to use/pass it as a binding to another view.  When you create a `@State var ...`, see:
[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) 
 **initialize it**, and when that value changes, SwiftUI updates the parts of the view hierarchy that depend on the value.
 See also 
[Managing state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state)
 for more examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

`@State` is designed to be a source of truth so you should not try to init it with data that can change. Because if it has a dependency then it is no longer a source of truth and bad things will happen.

Another way to solve the problem is put both properties in an `@State` struct and use `didSet` to update the other one.

Also, you need to be careful you don't break `Text`'s localization, e.g. when storing formatted strings, you need to use `LocalizedStringKey` instead of `String`.